# How print the array in another class?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, i have a class where i have my arrays in, which is like this

```
    public final class DepotDatabase {
    private Driver[] arrayDrivers;

     public DepotDatabase() {
        arrayDrivers = new Driver[4];

    arrayDrivers[0] = new Driver(1234, 1234, 0); // sample driver
    arrayDrivers[1] = new Driver(4444, 4444, 0); // sample driver
    arrayDrivers[2] = new Driver(1337, 1337, 1);   // sample manager
    arrayDrivers[3] = new Driver(1234, 1234, 0); // sample driver

}
```

and i want to print this array in another class, i did set up the array in another class

```
public Driver(int username, int password, int managerCheck) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.managerCheck = managerCheck;
}
```

but now i want to be able to print out all the drivers, but in another class which will be called ViewDrivers or something similar

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Can't you provide a `public` accessor for the array?

Comment: or a public `getDriversArray()` method?

Comment: read the Answer and comment I got from @Salah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method inside `DepotDatabase` to print the array, then create an object from and call print method.

```
public final class DepotDatabase {
private Driver[] arrayDrivers;

public void printArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayDrivers.length; i++) {
        Driver d = arrayDrivers[i];

        System.out.println("Username : " + d.getUsername());
        System.out.println("Password : " + d.getPassword());
        System.out.println(" Manager Check: " + d.getManagerCheck());

    }
}
```

the from the test class you can do:

```
public void execute() {
    DepotDatabase  ddb = new DepotDatabase();
    ddb.printArray();
}
```

Comment: How will i be able to print the actual array out? Because:DepotDatabase  ddb = new DepotDatabase();
ddb.printArray(); doesn't print out anything

Comment: Oh, Yea it doesn't print any thing yet until you add the code responsible to print the actual Array, i already left you a comment to add that code, anyway, do you want me to show you how to loop over array and print its values ?

Comment: That would help me a lot. Just so you know, in the class where I want to print the array, the code is placed under public void execute() So it will work in the main class, i know it may sound wierd. And i have to print like this using "screen" screen.displayMessageLine("");

Comment: And also, because i have the arrays called arrayDriver[0] and [1] how do I print all the drivers?

Comment: @user3383541 see my updated answer, please notice that you have to create a getter methods to Driver attributes.

Comment: This solves my problem! Thank You! It works just fine.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to do this haha :)

Answer (score 1):

That's why you'll need to have *getters* and *setters*. You should have:

```
public Driver[] getDrivers() {
    return arrayDrivers;
}
```

and in the other class, you simply call it (and print it or whatever).

Read [this tutorial](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm).

Comment: do i have to set it in the calss where i have the arrays?

Comment: @user3383541 Take a minute, think about it and I'm sure you'll know the answer. Hint: Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to print your array in another class you show create an accessor to it.

The common pattern for Java is to use "`get` plus name off attribute", `getDrivers()` you should also avoid the class name in such geter as it may changed due to application life.

```
public final class DepotDatabase {

    //your code

    public Driver[] getDrivers() {
       return this.arrayDrivers;
    }

}
```

Next question to answer is a returning the whole array is good idea. When you return it as above you loose control on it. And every one that call that method will be able to change the content of it.

To prevent this you should use so called [Defensive copying](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15)

```
   public Driver[] getDrivers() {
      return Arrays.copyOf(arrayDrivers, arrayDrivers.length);
   }
```

Then person will get an copy of it an will not harm your class.

The issue with this is that consumer of your class will have to call this method every time to get fresh list of cars.

To solve this issue you may want to user the [collection framework] where instead of array you cold define:

`List<Driver> drivers new ArrayList<>();`

and provide the drivers as [immutable] list

```
  public Iterable<Driver> getDrivers() {
          return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(drivers);
   }
```

`Iterable` is an interface, that allow you to obtain an interator the the list consumer of class wold have possibility to traverse it. IF you wan to allow him to check that list contains some driver you can set the return type as `Collection`

---

```
    class Storage {

        private String items[] = new String[10];

        public String[] getItems() {
            return Arrays.copyOf(items, items.length);
        }
    }

    class Store {

        Storage storage = new Storage();

        private void printStorage() {

            String[] items = storage.getItems();

            for (String item : items) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have used your code above in the class with the arrays  return Arrays.copyOf(arrayDrivers, arrayDrivers.length);, but I'm having problems calling this method in another class. Maybe I can't understand it, and i did have the Defensive Copying in the class where I want to print the array.

Comment: Start with basic example. To exchange data between class. you will need to have same context so it might be that something other is wrong.